# Access Query - Add column to count matching values in another query

Tags: ms-access

I would like to add another column to this query that counts the number of matching [ip_address] values from another query called [qry_ip_blacklist]

```
SELECT tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address, tbl_ip_addresses.selected
FROM tbl_ip_addresses
WHERE (tbl_ip_addresses.selected=True);
```

I have tried the following for the new column:

Expr1:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM qry_ip_blacklist WHERE ip_address = ip_address)
```

But this seems to show the total number of records in [qry_ip_blacklist]

How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question you want to perform the first query with a new column showing the number of ip_address in qry_ip_blacklist table.

If thats so and tbl_ip_addresses doesn't have more columns this query will do it:

```
SELECT tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address, tbl_ip_addresses.selected, COUNT(qry_ip_blacklist.ip_address )
FROM tbl_ip_addresses
LEFT JOIN qry_ip_blacklist 
ON qry_ip_blacklist .ip_address = tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address
WHERE (tbl_ip_addresses.selected=True)
GROUP BY tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address, tbl_ip_addresses.selected
```

In case that this query still doesn't work you can do the query for address with blacklist ip address and another one for those who doesn't have:

```
SELECT tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address, tbl_ip_addresses.selected, COUNT(qry_ip_blacklist.ip_address)
FROM tbl_ip_addresses
INNER JOIN qry_ip_blacklist ON qry_ip_blacklist .ip_address = tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address
WHERE (tbl_ip_addresses.selected=True)
GROUP BY tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address, tbl_ip_addresses.selected
UNION
SELECT tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address, tbl_ip_addresses.selected, 0
FROM tbl_ip_addresses
WHERE (tbl_ip_addresses.selected=True) AND tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address NOT INT (SELECT ip_addresses FROM qry_ip_blacklist)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I'm looking for the new column to show a count of '1' if the same value is also in [qry_ip_blackilist].

Comment: Access shows the following (it adds "As Expr 1": 

SELECT tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address, tbl_ip_addresses.selected, Count(*) AS Expr1
FROM tbl_ip_addresses LEFT JOIN qry_ip_blacklist ON tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address = qry_ip_blacklist.ip_address
WHERE (((tbl_ip_addresses.selected)=True))
GROUP BY tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address, tbl_ip_addresses.selected;

I removed a matching value from [qry_ip_blacklist] and the results is still '1'.  It should now be '0'

(sorry for double post)

Comment: Yeah sorry, this might be due left join that returns a row even when there is no content. Right now I don't have access, but you can try the query with `COUNT(qry_ip_blacklist.ip_address)` (already edited my answer).

Comment: Thank you OriolBG, your edited 1st solution works and so does your second solution.  As well as the solution from Luke Wage.  I will look into all 3 so that I can understand this better and decide which works best in my application.  I'm new to this forum (as you can probably tell, so I'm not sure what to do with this question(!)  I guess I hit the up arrows for both questions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to add a GROUP BY clause to the blacklist query:

```
SELECT 
 tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address
,tbl_ip_addresses.selected
,BlackList.Count

FROM tbl_ip_addresses 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(qry_ip_blacklist.ip_address) AS Count, qry_ip_blacklist.ip_address
FROM qry_ip_blacklist
GROUP BY qry_ip_blacklist.ip_address) AS BlackList 
ON tbl_ip_addresses.ip_address = BlackList.ip_address

WHERE tbl_ip_addresses.selected = True;
```

Comment: Thanks Luke Wage, that works :D You've both helped brilliantly - I'm just not sure what to do to close this question and make sure you both get your credits